# Get attachments list of mail by mail.id from folder other than inbox exchangelib python

Tags: python, email, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I am having great time while working with this library.

**My requirement is to get mail attachments from sub folder of inbox from mail id.**

So far I got to know that from mail id(Message id) we can get that particular mail.

Code I am using for mail id -

**Fetching mail from inbox and after moving that to different folder**

`account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received').reverse()` getting mail from inbox - email

`email.move(account.inbox / "sub_folder_of_inbox")`

`email.id` We have only this email id - this is some large string

Now mail is moved to ***sub_folder_of_inbox*** and we have id of mail too (from above code),

***Requirement is to get attachments of that mail.***

Code I followed-

```
sub_folder_mails=sub_folder_of_inbox.filter(message_id__in=['some large string mail id'])
for mail in sub_folder_mails:
      print(mail.subject)
```

***And after getting mail I can get attachments***

But this code is not giving required result , I am getting sub_folder_mails as QuerySet

Answer (score 0):

To get an item by ID, do this:

```py
item = a.root.get(id="AAMkADQy=")
```

Documented in https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#searching

Attachments on an item can be accessed via `item.attachment`. See https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#attachments